# Tengo un problema. Quiero hacer una conexion remota a mi servidor, pero no encuentro la manera... Debo hacerlo desde el puerto 3390

Tags: servidor

Quiero hacer una conexion remota a un servidor desde el puerto 3390. No cuento con mucha experiencia en cuanto a servidores... Espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

Intente usar el puerto 3390 para obtener la conexion remota con mi servidor pero no he tenido exito. Quiero poder asignar especificamente este puerto para realizar dicho cometido.

Comment: que tipo de servidor es? que as configurado? creastes los port forwarding en el router?

Comment: Hola, buenas tardes. Es un servidor Windows Server 2019 Standard... Justamente los port forwarding no me es posible configurarlos por el puerto 3390, use algunos programas para poder abrir el puerto pero no funciono.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a una sesión de *Escritorio Remoto de Windows*?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.